# ListViewItem Hover effect

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

How can I achieve a hover affect for a Listview item like in the Windows 10 Universal News app? When the item is touched or hover with the mouse there is a zoomming effect with a gray border arount that item. 
You can see in the pictures.

[image: Normal Style]

[image: Hover Style]

Edit: 
I tried to change the FocusBorderBrush from ListViewItem like this.

Adding this to app.xaml

```
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter 
                                       FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource GreenBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                       />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GreenBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Green" />
```

this is my listview:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>     
    </ListView>
```

But this change only the border color when the item has the focus.

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do something like the news app, not only on focus the item?

Comment: Did you try *anything* ?

Comment: @thomas see edited post

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the App file and edit as you require. this is a default style for the ListView, You will not need all of it but i just thought it would be better to show you everything that can be changed,the part you need is FocusBorderBrush, and the pointer over properties. Take care.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                           CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                                           CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                                           CheckMode="Inline"
                                           ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                           ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                           DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                                           DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                           DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                                           FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
                                           FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                           PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
                                           PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
                                           PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
                                           ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                           SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
                                           SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
                                           SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
                                           SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
                                           SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: i tried this but get the error message "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key TransparentBackgroundThemeBrush"

Comment: Sorry, i posted with some of my ThemeResources in it, Try that now.

Comment: ok that works. But do I have to make my own theme brush to change the FocusBorderBrush?

Comment: You can set it to a windows system colour, or you can create a brush using hex colours.

Comment: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WhiteBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="White" />`

Comment: I've edited the first post with an example, but the FocusBorderBrush is not what is used in the news app